# iptables and NetworkManager on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, networkmanager

I want to use iptables configuration on my Ubuntu 10.0.4 desktop, however I read that Network Manager and iptables have some conflicts. Should I uninstall NetworkManager? If yes, how?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using iptables with NetworkManager as long as the rules refer to local interfaces (or nothing local at all) instead of local IP addresses.

Comment: well the rules might refer to local IP addresses, for example port forwarding rule from universe to lan PC.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try a SAAS solution for managing iptables -> https://www.efw.io/Forum it can do AWS cloud integration if needed.